# BeatifulSoup: Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: html, python

voy extraer el nombre de la compañia y la url de una lista de trabajos de linkedi
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=data%20scientist&location=Bogot%C3%A1%2C%20Distrito%20Capital%2C%20Colombia&geoId=102361989&trk=public_jobs_jobs-search-bar_search-submit&position=1&pageNum=0'

en #Compañia defino el fragmento de código que utilizo para extraer el nombre de la compañía, pero al correrlo

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-83059f9e7a38> in <module>
     15   company1= job.find('h4', class_ ='base-search-card__subtitle')
     16   company2=company1.find('a', class_='hidden-nested-link')
---> 17   company2.text.strip()
     18   Company.append(company2.text.strip())
     19 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

````
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import pandas as pd

# ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=data%20scientist&location=Bogot%C3%A1%2C%20Distrito%20Capital%2C%20Colombia&geoId=102361989&trk=public_jobs_jobs-search-bar_search-submit&position=1&pageNum=0'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

jobs = soup.find('ul',attrs={"class": "jobs-search__results-list"})
alljobs=jobs.find_all('li')

Company = []
Url = []

i=0
while i<=(len(alljobs)-1):
  job=alljobs[i]
   
  #Compañia
  company1= job.find('h4', class_ ='base-search-card__subtitle')
  company2=company1.find('a', class_='hidden-nested-link')
  company2.text.strip()
  Company.append(company2.text.strip())
  
  #Url
  Url1= job.find('h4', class_ ='base-search-card__subtitle')
  Url2=Url1.find('a', class_='hidden-nested-link')
  Url2.get('href')
  Url.append(Url2.get('href'))
  
  i=i+1
   
df_jobs= pd.DataFrame({'Company': Company, 'Url': Url })
df_jobs

    ```
````

Comment: Quiere decir que no lo encontró, revisa que realmente sí haya un `h4', class_ ='base-search-card__subtitle'`

Answer (score 0):

Despues de revisar tu codigo pude encontrar 4 errores del mismo tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En teoría general cuando intentas buscar

- `company1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link")`
- `Url1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link")`

Los mismos NO EXISTEN devolviendo `None` y no puedes aplicar el metodo de `text` ni `get` sobre un elemento de tipo `NoneType` y por consiguiente la ejecucion se rompe.

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar [`try/except`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) para controlar los errores y decidir que hacer en caso de encontrar alguno.

Ejemplo:

```
i = 0
while i <= (len(alljobs) - 1):
    job = alljobs[i]
    try:
        # Compañia
        company1 = job.find("h4", class_="base-search-card__subtitle")
        company2 = company1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link")    
        Company.append(company2.text.strip())
    except AttributeError as error:
        # HANDLE COMPANY ERROR
        print("Company Error: ", error)
        
    try:
        # Url
        Url1 = job.find("h4", class_="base-search-card__subtitle")
        Url2 = Url1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link")
        Url2.get("href")
        Url.append(Url2.get("href"))
    except AttributeError as error:
        # HANDLE Url ERROR
        print("URL Error: ", error)
    
    i = i + 1
```

## UPDATE 1

Tomando en consideración el comentario de "@Candid Moe"

Puedes validar si URL1 y Company1 no son `None` en lugar de manejar como un error.

```
i = 0
while i <= (len(alljobs) - 1):
    job = alljobs[i]
    # Compañia
    company1 = job.find("h4", class_="base-search-card__subtitle")
    if company1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link") is not None:
        company2 = company1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link")    
        Company.append(company2.text.strip())
        
    # Url
    Url1 = job.find("h4", class_="base-search-card__subtitle")
    if Url1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link") is not None:
        Url2 = Url1.find("a", class_="hidden-nested-link")
        Url2.get("href")
        Url.append(Url2.get("href"))
    
    i = i + 1
```

Espero sea de ayuda!

Comment: Que el método `find()` retorne `None` no es un error ni una excepción. Es un resultado válido que debería manejarse en-línea con `if Url1:`.

Comment: En donde lees que `find()` es un error?

Comment: Cuando usas `try/except` en lugar de `if Url1:` except diciendo implicitamente que `find()` retorna un resultado erroneo.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, fueron de gran ayuda